# Unexpected behaviour when updating variables in Schematics using the golang SDK

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-schematics

I want to update variables in schematics workspaces programmatically using the golang SDK, so what I am doing is a call to

`_, detailedResponse , err := schematicsService.ReplaceWorkspace(updateWorkspaceOptions)`

This is woking so far, in Schematics I can see the variables are beeing updated.
The thing that is bothering me, "plan" says there is nothing to be changed.

If I go and use the Schematics GUI, then plan will register the changes.

What am I missing? Does anyone have an example of this call? Unfortunately in the API-Docs there is no example.

Comment: Fixed: After a closer look at the github I figured out that I have been using the wrong mehtod. Instead, I took 
schematicsService.ReplaceWorkspaceInputs(updateWorkspaceOptions) and everything worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Used  `_, detailedResponse , err := schematicsService.ReplaceWorkspaceInputs(updateWorkspaceOptions)` instead and it worked fine.